# How to put SELECT inside trigger in IBM DB2

Tags: sql, sqlite, db2

I want my database to show the table every time while I insert a new row. My code is able to compile but It don't show the table after I insert a new row.

Below is my code :

```
create trigger show_all                                                                       
after insert ON Toy                                                                           
for each row mode db2sql                                                                      
select * from Toy
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't possible.

Triggers don't return a value to the statement (insert) that caused the trigger to fire. Further, that behaviour wouldn't even be possible because multiple triggers could fire in response to an insert, which would get to return something?

You could create a stored procedure that performs an insert and then returns the result of a select, and then call that function instead of inserting directly.